# Comparing Features in Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap

What I am trying to do is, compare attributes in a shapefile to another updated version of that same shapefile just in a different folder. Right now I am just using the Compare Feature tool, which works okay, its just a rather long process when you have 3000 shapefiles to compare.  Instead of one file at a time, let it run through each of their respective folders and compare features that way.  I currently have code that will iterate through a folder, and I have the code that compares. Im just not sure how to put the two codes together. Is there a better way?
ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1, Python 2.7.5

First code snippet

```
import arcpy 
try:
 # Set local variables

    base_features = r"C:\Users\usr\Desktop\basepoints 2013\01001_points.shp"

    test_features = r"C:\Users\usr\Desktop\Testpoints apr2014\01001_points.shp"
    sort_field = "APN"
    compare_type = "GEOMETRY_ONLY"
    ignore_option = ""
    xy_tolerance = ".00000001 METERS"
    m_tolerance=".001"
    z_tolerance=".001"
    attribute_tolerance = "#"
    omit_field = "FID;Shape;PARCEL_ID;STATE_CODE;CNTY_CODE;APN2;OWNER;ADDR;CITY;STATE;ZIP;PLUS;STD_ADDR;STD_CITY;STD_STATE;STD_ZIP;STD_PLUS;TYPE_CODE;LONGITUDE;LATITUDE;CENSUS_TR;BLOCK_NBR;LOT_NBR;RANGE;TOWNSHIP;SECTION;QRT_SECT;FZ_COM_PNL;LAND_USE;CNTY_USE1;CNTY_USE2;M_HOME_IND;ZONING;PROP_IND;MUNI_NAME;MUNI_CODE;SUB_TR_NUM;SUB_PLT_BK;SUB_PLT_PG;SUB_NAME;FRONT_FT;DEPTH_FT;LAND_ACRES;LAND_SQ_FT;LOT_AREA;UBLD_SQ_FT;BLD_SQ_IND;FRPLCE_TYP;FRPLCE_NBR;FRPLCE_IND;PKG_SQ_FT;BSMT_SQ_FT;ADJ_SQ_FT;GR_SQ_FT;GF_SQ_FT;LIV_SQ_FT;BLD_SQ_FT;YR_BLT;EFF_YR_BLT;BEDROOMS;ROOMS;BATHS_CAL;BATHS;FULL_BATHS;HALF_BATHS;QTR1_BATHS;QTR3_BATHS;BATH_FIX;AIR_COND;BSMT_FNSH;BLD_CODE;BLD_IMP_CD;CONDITION;CONSTR_TYP;EXT_WALLS;FOUNDATION;FLOOR;FRAME;GARAGE;HEATING;PKG_SPACES;PKG_TYP;POOL;POOL_CD;QUALITY;ROOF_COVER;ROOF_TYP;STORY_CD;STORY_NBR;BLD_VIEW;LOC_INF;BLD_UNITS;STYLE;UNITS_NBR;ENERGY_USE;FUEL;SEWER;WATER"
    continue_compare = "CONTINUE_COMPARE"
    compare_file = r"C:\Users\usr\Desktop\compare_parcel_baja.txt"



    compare_result=arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(base_features, test_features, sort_field, compare_type, ignore_option, xy_tolerance, m_tolerance, z_tolerance, attribute_tolerance, omit_field, continue_compare, compare_file)
    print  compare_result.getOutput(1)
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Second code snippet

```
##======== iterating code ==============
import os.path

topdir= r"X:\CoreData_Jan15_2013\ParcelPoint\Data\points"

exten='.shp'

def step(ext,dirname,names):
    ext=ext.lower()

    for name in names:
        if name.lower().endswith(ext):
            print(os.path.join(dirname,name))

os.path.walk(topdir,step,exten)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the arcpy tools you could do this. Note that blank space in the folder name could be a source of errors.

```
import arcpy 

base_wksp = r"C:\\Users\\usr\\Desktop\\basepoints 2013\\"

test_wksp = r"C:\\Users\\usr\\Desktop\\Testpoints apr2014\\"

sort_field = "APN"
compare_type = "GEOMETRY_ONLY"
ignore_option = ""
xy_tolerance = ".00000001 METERS"
m_tolerance=".001"
z_tolerance=".001"
attribute_tolerance = "#"
omit_field = "FID;Shape;PARCEL_ID;STATE_CODE;CNTY_CODE;APN2;OWNER;ADDR;CITY;STATE;ZIP;PLUS;STD_ADDR;STD_CITY;STD_STATE;STD_ZIP;STD_PLUS;TYPE_CODE;LONGITUDE;LATITUDE;CENSUS_TR;BLOCK_NBR;LOT_NBR;RANGE;TOWNSHIP;SECTION;QRT_SECT;FZ_COM_PNL;LAND_USE;CNTY_USE1;CNTY_USE2;M_HOME_IND;ZONING;PROP_IND;MUNI_NAME;MUNI_CODE;SUB_TR_NUM;SUB_PLT_BK;SUB_PLT_PG;SUB_NAME;FRONT_FT;DEPTH_FT;LAND_ACRES;LAND_SQ_FT;LOT_AREA;UBLD_SQ_FT;BLD_SQ_IND;FRPLCE_TYP;FRPLCE_NBR;FRPLCE_IND;PKG_SQ_FT;BSMT_SQ_FT;ADJ_SQ_FT;GR_SQ_FT;GF_SQ_FT;LIV_SQ_FT;BLD_SQ_FT;YR_BLT;EFF_YR_BLT;BEDROOMS;ROOMS;BATHS_CAL;BATHS;FULL_BATHS;HALF_BATHS;QTR1_BATHS;QTR3_BATHS;BATH_FIX;AIR_COND;BSMT_FNSH;BLD_CODE;BLD_IMP_CD;CONDITION;CONSTR_TYP;EXT_WALLS;FOUNDATION;FLOOR;FRAME;GARAGE;HEATING;PKG_SPACES;PKG_TYP;POOL;POOL_CD;QUALITY;ROOF_COVER;ROOF_TYP;STORY_CD;STORY_NBR;BLD_VIEW;LOC_INF;BLD_UNITS;STYLE;UNITS_NBR;ENERGY_USE;FUEL;SEWER;WATER"
continue_compare = "CONTINUE_COMPARE"
compare_file = r"C:\\Users\\usr\\Desktop\\compare_parcel_baja\\"

arcpy.env.workspace = base_wksp
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs:
    compare_result=arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(base_wksp + fc, test_wksp + fc, sort_field, compare_type, ignore_option, xy_tolerance, m_tolerance, z_tolerance, attribute_tolerance, omit_field, continue_compare, compare_file + fc[:-4] + ".txt")
```

Comment: Everytime I run it, it brings back an error saying my base and test features do not exist. Im not sure why it would be doing that, because it does exist.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would there be a reason why that is happening?

Comment: The reason could be that you have a blank space in the names.

Comment: I had changed those before but now it works. For some reason it wasn't working with the back slashes in the filepath names. I changed those to front slashes and now it works beautiful!

Comment: Why are you escaping the backslashes while also using the raw string notation (`r"..."`)? Do one or the other, but not both.